# How to properly configure the Apc cache engine?

Tags: php, cakephp, caching, apc, cakephp-3.x

I'm facing problems when trying to configure `Cache` in Cakephp 3. My config is as follows:

```
Cache => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Apc',
        'path' => CACHE,
    ],
    '_cake_core_' => [
        'className' => 'Apc',
        'prefix' => 'mandealR_cake_core_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+2 minutes',
    ],
    '_cake_model_' => [
        'className' => 'Apc', 
        'prefix' => 'mandealR_cake_model_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => true, 
        'duration' => '+2 minutes', 
    ],
    'apc' => [
        'engine' => 'Apc' 
    ]
]
```

I can get

```
Cache engine Cake\Cache\Engine\ApcEngine is not properly configured.
```

Can someone help me finding the right config ?

Comment: Even though the problem may be obvious for people that know the Cake internals, please, whenever receiving errors, post not only the complete, exact error message, but also the related, full stacktrace (ideally copied from the logs where it it is available in a properly readable fashion)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### APCu as of CakePHP 3.2

As of CakePHP 3.2, the `Apc` cache engine doesn't actually use the `APC` extension anymore (which has been definitely discontinued ever since PHP 5.5 shipped with bundled opcode caching), but the `APCu` extension.

**http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php**

The migration guide as well as the caching docs seem to lack that information.

### Extension not loaded

The error you are receiving generally occours when the extension is not loaded - being it `APC` or `APCu` (`!extension_loaded('apc')` / `!extension_loaded('apcu')`). So make sure that you've configured your PHP installation properly, and that the required extension is installed/loaded.

### ps.

the `Apc` engine doesn't support a `path` option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I switched to `php` as default session manager. Though I've installed APC, and I'm using CakePHP 3.1.7, I still get the same error. Thanks again for your useful explanations.